# Linkedin API bad request when trying to like a post in a group

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am using Java with the Linkedin API to like posts groups. This is working on when the post is from someone of my network, but not when I am trying to like a post from a group.

```
OAuthRequest oAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{idPost}/relation-to-viewer/is-liked");
oAuthService.signRequest(oAuthToken, oAuthRequest);
oAuthRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

Element root = new Element("is-liked");
root.setText((likeIt) ? "true" : "false");
Document doc = new Document(root);

XMLOutputter outputter=new XMLOutputter();
StringWriter out=new StringWriter();
outputter.output(doc,out);
out.close();

oAuthRequest.addPayload(out.toString());
Response response = oAuthRequest.send();
```

Notice that the {id-post} is replaced by a correct id-post.

And the response always is Bad Request 400

Anyone face this problem before or I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The problem was while making the request. The discussion id (6014771303381291012) I was sending with URL was in wrong format. It should be like: g-GROUP_ID-S-DISCUSSION/POST_ID